# python django create own command and add list as parameter

Tags: python, django, command

I want to use py manage.py own_command.

I got the following code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'create user'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--username', type=str, help='set username')
        parser.add_argument('--password', type=str, help='set password')
        parser.add_argument('--email', type=str, help='set password')
        parser.add_argument('--group', type=list, default=[], action='append', help='set group(s) like ["basic", "advanced"]')
        parser.add_argument('--permission', type=list, default=[], action='append', help='set permission(s) like ["delete", "write"]')
```

```
>py manage.py create_app_user --username dustin --password hdf --email "" --group ["admin", "basic"
]
```

creates

> ```
> usage: manage.py create_app_user [-h] [--username USERNAME]
>                                  [--password PASSWORD] [--email EMAIL]
>                                  [--group GROUP] [--permission PERMISSION]
>                                  [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
>                                  [--settings SETTINGS]
>                                  [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
>                                  [--no-color]
> manage.py create_app_user: error: unrecognized arguments: basic
> ```

]

I found solutions for django <= 1.7 BUT not for >=2.1

Comment: Have you tried putting the --group parameter in quotes, e.g. '["admin", "basic"]'

Comment: @OsmanOmar its not duplicate, as I wrote in the bottom --> your ticket is solution for django <=1.7

Comment: @Steve, same erroursly output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to specify either `nargs='*'`, to allow 0 or more values, or `nargs='+'` to allow 1 or more values, eg:

```py
parser.add_argument(
    '--group',
    nargs='*',
    help='set group(s) like "basic", "advanced"',
)
```

Also, you need to call your command without square brackets or commas:

```
py manage.py create_app_user --username dustin --password hdf --email "" --group "admin" "basic"
```

Comment: almoust, but output ```group = kwargs['group']``` looks like ```member of group(s): [[['a', 'd', 'm', 'i', 'n'], ['b', 'a', 's', 'i', 'c']]]
```

Comment: Right, you actually don't need `type=list`, `action`, and `default`, they are inferred from `nargs`

Comment: perfect. ```parser.add_argument('--group', nargs='+', help='set group(s) like "basic" "advanced"')```

Comment: Cool, please accept the answer if it solved your issue